# PHP Search Query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, select

I am trying to do a search on my website but for some reason my SELECT query is swapping the keyword and name of the column name when it is executed. Below is code for my query:

```
if(empty($_POST)=== false){
    $output = '';
    $error = '';
    $input = $_POST['search_input'];
    $i=0;
    if($input){
        $keyword = explode(" ", $input);
        require ('core/dbconnection.php');
        //If a user is logged in check if the user is Admin or Customer. 
        if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){ 
            if($admin == 1){
                //enter admin code here
            }
        }else{
            //If user is not logged in search items table only.
            $search_items = "SELECT * FROM fyp_items WHERE ";
            foreach($keyword as $k){
                $i++;
                if($i == 1){
                    $search_items .= "name LIKE $k OR description LIKE $k";
                }else
                    $search_items .= " OR name LIKE $k OR description LIKE $k";
            }
            $item_qry = mysql_query($search_items)or die(mysql_error());

        }
    }else
        $error = '<p class="pageerror">Please enter your search terms.</p>';
```

The `$search_items` is concatanating the search query which is then executed by `$item_query` .

So I searched for "conwerse" and echo'ed out the `$search_items`variable I got the following:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0302ft5mc3

However, when I run the query I get this mysql_error...
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0552ft6bb4

Seems like it swaps the keyword and column name when I run the query. My database tables are of type InnoDB> I would much appreciate your help!

Comment: Enclose them in quotes `''`, like `description LIKE '$k'` or it's considered to be a column.

Comment: I'd like to warn you that you have a pretty open SQL injection issue there as well; also, your MySQL extension is deprecated and I highly recommend switching over to either MySQLi or PDO MySQL or similar; and perhaps extend your security with some regular expression functions to clear all unwanted characters away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, dont use mysql_query as all mysql_ functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo.

Second, escape your keywords with  `mysql_escape_string();`, like

```
$k = mysql_real_escape_string($k);
```

Third, your query, when you echo it, needs to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fyp_items WHERE `name` LIKE 'conwerse' OR `description` LIKE 'conwerse';
```

There is more, but this should get you started.

Comment: Actually; use of `mysql_escape_string` is highly not recommended as it _doesn't_ strip anything _at the end of the day_. Using `mysql_real_escape_string` is recommended; though it is wiser to just move to MySQLi or PDO like you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you advice @D. Kasipovic. Helped very much! Now i connect to the database and I can carry out the search. But it says items are not found even when they are in the database. This is my corrected code..

Comment: `$search_items = "SELECT * FROM fyp_items WHERE ";
   foreach($keyword as $k){
     $k = mysql_real_escape_string($k);
     $i++;
     if($i == 1){
        $search_items .= "name LIKE '".$k."' OR description LIKE '".$k."'";
 }else
 $search_items .= " OR name LIKE '".$k."' OR description LIKE '".$k."'";}
 $item_qry = mysql_query("$search_items")or die(mysql_error());
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($item_qry);
 if($numrows > 0){
       $output = 'found it';
 }else
 $error = '<p class="pageerror">Sorry, what you were looking for was not found.</p>';`

Comment: Note that I changed to mysqli and it threw errors, namely that mysqli_query takes 2 parameters and that I've only provided 1. I read a php script and know how to fix it but I need to make sure the query is working first.

Comment: Well, `echo` the query when it is finished generating, and then try it manually in the sql window?